# How to break html page into multiple pages with a continue button at end of each page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web development. I have been searching for but have not been able to find out about how to break html page into multiple pages with a continue button at end of each page? Please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: We really need more details.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the term [`pagination`](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=pagination), and there are a large number of ways you can do this.  Implementation details are highly specific to the language being used, so without any more details we can't help.

Comment: I want to do it in html5 page, using javascript is fine but not sure if it would be required.

Comment: OK.  Again, as I said, there are a large number of ways you can go about it, including examples and tutorials you can follow from a the google search I included above.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there are a lot of ways to approach this, however as you are looking for a solely HTML approach, you can look into using

```html
<a href="/page2.html">Continue</a>
```

This is a quick and dirty approach for you.

Comment: I do not want to explicitly create a new HTML page but rather split the content of an existing HTML page into two pages

Comment: I suggest you look at: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp